# How to show new window when href from Edge IE Mode to Edge without call window

Tags: internet-explorer

In Edge IE Mode, when a new window is forced to appear on MS Edge(none ie mode) without Edge call window.

Run Edge on A (Edge IE MODE), and B is called Edge none IE MODE. However, window A does not close automatically.

[image: 1]

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
{
    location.href = 'microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com';
}

function popup(){
  let options = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,status=no,menubar=no";
  window.open("microsoft-edge:"+"https://www.google.com", options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer">href direct</a><br>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="test();">location</a><br>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="popup();">window open</a><br>
<br>
<a href="microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">onclick</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `microsoft-edge` protocol to switch to Edge browser won't close the original window because protocols are used to open an App. It is not the same as opening a page where you can add `_blank` or `_self` in your code.

Of course, you can add `window.close()` right after `location.href` or `window.open()` to close the original window. But it only works in IE mode. In other browsers like Chrome, the original window is still there.